# Flex: Getting "a bunch" of data from Flex into an HTML page?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I've got a bunch (say, 1k) of data in Flex, and I want to get that data to an HTML page, where some JavaScript will slice-and-dice the data and generate a report.

What's the simplest way to get it there?

I've considered passing it as part of the url, for example:

```
navigateToUrl("report.html?data=" + serialized_report_data)
```

But, apart from being more than a little bit hacky, URLs aren't supposed to be "that long", so it could cause problems.

Alternately, I could use an HTTPService to post the data to a server, which would send a URL back to Flex, then Flex could `navigateToUrl` that URL, which would show the data. This would work, but it also seems more complex than it needs to be.

So, is there any better way?

Answer (score 4):

Read about the [ExternalInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=externalinterface). You can pass data back and forth between Javascript and Flash in the same browser.

Comment: I'd thought about that, but the problem is that it's in the same browser window. I want the reports to open in a new window.

Now, I guess I could use ExternalInterface to pass the data to JavaScript in the *same* window, then let that JavaScript do the messy business of opening up a new window… But that's starting to get pretty complex >_<

Comment: Use ExternalInterface to put the data in a form and the cause the form to POST itself to the report page.